# how to use the group by clause

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a query usign the clause group by

Such query returns 2 rows, that are 2 groups

I'd like to extract ONE record belonging to the first group and ONE record belonging to the second group

How do I achieve that ?

In Postgresql